# Use data from database in Chart.js/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to show a line chart on my "Weights" index page with Chart.js in my Rails app (a weight loss app). I have a table that holds a user's weight (as "kilograms") for each day (as "day"). I am able to show a line chart, however, but only with static data - not with the data from my Weights table.

What I want to do now is to have "day" on the x-axis and "kilograms" on the y-axis.

How can I achieve this? And as I just started coding few months ago: how should the code look like?

Thx a lot.

This is the code from my weights index.html.erb:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["day 1", "day 2", "day 3", "day 4", "day 5", "day 6"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My Weight',
            data: [82.4, 79.6, 79.3, 78.4, 77.5, 75.1],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I feel your pain.  Setting up chart.js the right way on rails took me weeks lol I'll help ya out.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing that had me stuck forever was that Chart.js relies on calling its tooltiptemplate with `<%` however this would then be interpreted by ERB and cause a problem.  The workaround is adding another `%` which tells erb not to interpret the tags it otherwise would have.  That's not very well documented but what are you going to do.  As for the rest, in your view-page.html.erb file you want to add the chart scripts at the bottom:

Set your timeline X-Axis (I'll show you how to load it dynamically but this could be static if you want in which case just enter them directly into the timeline array):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      var lineData = {
      <% timeline = []
         datapoints = []
        @workout.each do |workout|
          timeline << workout.day
          datapoints << workout.weight
       end
 %>
       //The "raw" method is needed to stop the auto escaping of the output.  Test this out in your console and you will notice the output is formatted like "[\"January\", \"February\", \"March\", \"April\", \"May\", \"June\", \"July\"]"  This escaping of quotes causes errors in js...
      labels: <%= raw timeline.to_json %>,
        datasets: [{
                label: "Weight Gain/Loss",
                fillColor: "rgba(26,179,148,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#127A65",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: <%= raw datapoints.to_json %>,
            }]
    };
```

If you want to set some options remember to use the `<%%` tag for tooltips!

```
var lineOptions = {
            scaleOverride : true,
            tooltipTemplate: "<%%if (label){%>(<%%=label%>) <%%}%><%%= value %>  pounds",
    };
    //NOTE THE ABOVE TOOLTIP REQUIRES A SECOND % SIGN ON OPENING TAGS SO THAT IS IS TAKEN LITERALLY AND NOT INTERPRETED BY RAILS ERB!!!!!!!!

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the instructions. Still struggling with Chart.js so I switched to highcharts. Somehow this works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was struggling with getting this to work on Rails, but I discovered that I did not have to use the Rails template escape characters that chart.js says that you do. In my case (needing to show a zero in the label when the value is set to 0.1), this is what I did:

```
tooltipTemplate: function(context){
  var labelVal = (context.value == '0.1')? '0' : context.value;
  var newLabel = context.label + ': ' + labelVal;
  return newLabel;
}
```